# Tensor.eval() gives no output. Just a blinking cursor in IPython notebook

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, ipython

I am trying to read multiple images in tensorflow and here is my code which i have taken from a stackoverflow

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession() 
filenames = ['/Users/darshak/TensorFlow/1.jpg', '/Users/darshak/TensorFlow/10.jpg']
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, content = reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)
```

Now when I run,

```
image.eval()
```

I get no output. Just a blinking cursor. How can I see if something is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the queue runners. Just add the following after creating the session, and before evaluating `image`.

```
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
```

For more, check out [Threading and Queues](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues).